# Twilio- using webhook to a second phone number to dialogue with customer

Tags: twilio, sms, twilio-studio

I'm using Twilio Studio and have two phone numbers.
I want to start a text conversation (A) with the customer and after a certain event (like keyword "manager") occurs, I want to alert a second text conversation (B) from a new phone number with that same customer.
I was thinking it might work to forward a message from (A) to (B), but I'm not sure how to give B the phone number that (A) was texting.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'm a newbie so take what I say with a grain of salt...
I'm almost positive there are 3 or 4 tutorials that you can link together to solve your issue. I think I've read/watched all of them 4x in the last 3 days trying to self learn.

To be honest, from what I've gathered in my self teachings your answers lie within their YouTube channel and their help docs on Functions, Webhooks, HTTP Requests and maybe even TwiML Redirects. But again, I'm a new guy.

If someone who is more knowledgeable doesn't respond back then I'll try to help you because I think I can if you can bear with me. Just reply with a tag so I'll get an alert. Good Luck (to us both!)

Answer (score 0):

you can retrieve the phone number of the customer by referencing off any text you sent/received from the costumer in the flow.

For instance a if you texted them it would be `{{widgets.your_widgets_name_here.outbound.To}}`

Then just type in this syntax `{{widgets.your_widgets_name_here.outbound.To}}` in the message body of the widget you are using to alert conversation (B).

It will display the Number of the costumer.

You could then put that in the send message field of any widget in that conversation by refrencing the same way `{{widgets.your_widgets_name_here.inbound.body}}`